# how to simply align semicolon from strings in Python?

Tags: python

I need to align semicolon in strings. For Example:

```
Input:
  1-1: abc
  1-2-1: defghi
  1-2-1a: jklmnopqr
  1-2-1a-1-1-1a: stuvwxyz

Ouput:
  1-1          : abc
  1-2-1        : defghi
  1-2-1a       : jklmnopqr
  1-2-1a-1-1-1a: stuvwxyz
```

And the following is my solution.

```
strs = ['1-1: abc', '2-2-2: defghi', '3-3-3b: jklmnopqr', '1-2-1a-1-1-1a: stuvwxyz']
lengths = [s.find(':') for s in strs]
for i, s in enumerate(strs):
  if lengths[i] == -1:
    new_strs.append(s)
  else:
    new_strs.append(s[:lengths[i]] + ' ' * (max(lengths) - lengths[i]) + s[lengths[i]:])
```

Is there any simple way to implement? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions like `ljust` and `rjust` are your friends when trying to align output:

```
>>> aligned = [f"{s.split(':')[0].ljust(max(s.index(':') for s in strs))}:{s.split(':')[1]}" for s in strs]
>>> print("\n".join(aligned))
1-1          : abc
2-2-2        : defghi
3-3-3b       : jklmnopqr
1-2-1a-1-1-1a: stuvwxyz
```

or a little less compactly:

```
>>> i = max(s.index(":") for s in strs)
>>> cols = [s.split(":") for s in strs]
>>> aligned = [f"{c[0].ljust(i)}:{c[1]}" for c in cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python f-strings let you reference variables in the current namespace. In addition, its format specification also allows field descriptors to come from variables also. After splitting out the two parts of the string, find the longest value to the left of the colon and you have the padding for all of them.

```
>>> strs = ['1-1: abc', '2-2-2: defghi', '3-3-3b: jklmnopqr', '1-2-1a-1-1-1a: stuvwxyz']
>>> parts = [s.split(":", 1) for s in strs]
>>> field_len = max(len(p[0]) for p in parts)
>>> for p0, p1 in parts:
...     print(f"{p0:<{field_len}s}: {p1}")
... 
1-1          :  abc
2-2-2        :  defghi
3-3-3b       :  jklmnopqr
1-2-1a-1-1-1a:  stuvwxyz
```